# Control.Invalidate() or Control.Invalidate(Rectangle)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Should I use `Control.Invalidate()` or preferably `Control.Invalidate(Rectangle)`? MSDN is a bit short on information for those methods.

In both cases the same `OnPaint` method is called and the same lines of code are executed. So what is the difference here, except that I have to calculate the rectangle structure to tell windows which area should be redrawn?

I feel like I'm much safer just using `Control.Invalidate()` all the time, but at the same time I feel like I wrote bad code and lost performance.

Comment: If you want to invalidate the entire thing, use just Invalidate(). if you want to invalidate only part of the control, then use the Rectangle method. It's just an optimization technique. You should be fine just using Invalidate() by itself. Most of the time this stuff is double-buffered, and from what I understand the entire thing is redrawn anyway. I think this `InvalidateRect` stuff is artifacts from a time when CPU and GPU power was very limited. That really isn't the case anymore, especially with the GDI.

Comment: Invalidate(Rectangle) only makes sense if you can redraw part of the area in the Paint event. And if whole area are always redrawn, there is no sense.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, that's not true. You always do ALL of the drawing in the `Paint` event handler. That is completely unrelated to `Invalidate`. You do all the drawing every time and then only the part of your drawing that falls in the invalidated area actually gets painted to the screen. It's the painting part, not the drawing part, that is slow.

Answer (score 2):

You should always invalidate the smallest area possible, so you should pass a `Rectangle` or `Region` unless the entire control area has or may have changed. The reason for that is that it is the actual painting of pixels to the scree that is the slowest part of the whole operation and every pixel within the invalidated area will be repainted. The fewer pixels that is, the faster the repainting will be.

You may not always be able to see the difference but, especially if you're repainting often, there can be a visible performance difference. It is generally much quicker to perform a mildly complex calculation to determine what the smallest `Rectangle` or `Region` would be than to repaint the extra pixels.

Comment: Maybe I underestimated the costs of a drawing method. How would you deal with a method provided by a customer that draws outside of the specified region (specified within `Graphics.Clip`) by changing it? There's no guarantee that the region I passed in earlier is the same that he used to draw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If a method is drawing then presumably the `Paint` event has already been raised so `Invalidate` has already been called. That means that the area that may have changed should already have been calculated and specified when `Invalidate` was called. You should not be asking new questions in the comments of an answer to an existing question. If you have a new question then post a new question with all the information relevant to that question.

Comment: @keco You can have the client pass the coordinates of the part of the image that was drawn to. You then use those as params to `Control.Invalidate()`.